# communicate to virtual serial port after SSH

Tags: java, ssh

I want to communicate to a virtual Serial Port of my server . Steps involved in this is.

```
1.SSH in to iLO 
2.enter vsp command
3.A virtual serial port session is opened 
4.it asks for server credentials and then
it gives us a server terminal experience we can send any
command as we do in a terminal opened in the server itself
```

So my aim is to automate all the above steps in any way from java.

I have completed the first two steps via jsch but once it enters into virtual serial port session im not able to communicate .
I also tried automating the terminal commands using expect for linux in expect even I see the same pattern once it enters into VSP session I'm not able to communicate I tried autoexpect also it didn't work
Below is my jsch code

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host="10.10.100.209";
    String user="administrator";
    String password="2xR3M0t3$$";
    String command1="vsp";     
    try{
        
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.setCommand("vsp");
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        channel.connect();

  byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        
        while(true){
          while(in.available()>0){
            int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if(i<0)break;
            System.out.print("out"+new String(tmp, 0, i));
          
           
            
          }
         
          if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
          }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
```

Now my question is how to communicate to virtual serial port after I ssh into my iLO.

Answer (score 0):

Use ChannelShell instead of ChannelExec.

- [ChannelShell](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html) is like using interactive shell.
- [ChannelExec](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html) is like executing shell script.

Your use case seems to be interactive.

Comment: Same thing happens in Channelshell even not proceeding after in enters the VSp session

Comment: Can you include inputstream data in your question?